# Running Spring Boot Tests using @DataJpaTest and @Testcontainers results into ddl exceptions

Tags: spring-boot, spring-data-jpa, spring-boot-test, testcontainers, data-jpa-test

A minimal Example can be found here: https://github.com/jbcbezerra/springboot-tc/tree/master/src/test/java/com/example/test

When using Spring Boot 3.1 and trying to Test a Repository, where the tests connects to a mysql container instead to a embedded database and furthermore using the `@DataJpaTest` Annotation, i always get a ddl exception thrown like follows:

```
Hibernate: alter table tab_house drop foreign key FK_HOUSE_PRO
2023-05-26T13:22:51.438+02:00  WARN 249837 --- [           main] o.h.t.s.i.ExceptionHandlerLoggedImpl     : GenerationTarget encountered exception accepting command : Error executing DDL "alter table tab_house drop foreign key FK_HOUSE_PRO" via JDBC [Table 'test.tab_house' doesn't exist]

org.hibernate.tool.schema.spi.CommandAcceptanceException: Error executing DDL "alter table tab_house drop foreign key FK_HOUSE_PRO" via JDBC [Table 'test.tab_house' doesn't exist]
    at org.hibernate.tool.schema.internal.exec.GenerationTargetToDatabase.accept(GenerationTargetToDatabase.java:92) ~[hibernate-core-6.2.2.Final.jar:6.2.2.Final]
    at org.hibernate.tool.schema.internal.Helper.applySqlString(Helper.java:235) ~[hibernate-core-6.2.2.Final.jar:6.2.2.Final]
    at org.hibernate.tool.schema.internal.Helper.applySqlStrings(Helper.java:219) ~[hibernate-core-6.2.2.Final.jar:6.2.2.Final]
    at org.hibernate.tool.schema.internal.SchemaDropperImpl.applyConstraintDropping(SchemaDropperImpl.java:455) ~[hibernate-core-6.2.2.Final.jar:6.2.2.Final]
    at org.hibernate.tool.schema.internal.SchemaDropperImpl.dropConstraintsTablesSequences(SchemaDropperImpl.java:242) ~[hibernate-core-6.2.2.Final.jar:6.2.2.Final]
    at org.hibernate.tool.schema.internal.SchemaDropperImpl.dropFromMetadata(SchemaDropperImpl.java:215) ~[hibernate-core-6.2.2.Final.jar:6.2.2.Final]
    at org.hibernate.tool.schema.internal.SchemaDropperImpl.performDrop(SchemaDropperImpl.java:185) ~[hibernate-core-6.2.2.Final.jar:6.2.2.Final]
    at org.hibernate.tool.schema.internal.SchemaDropperImpl.doDrop(SchemaDropperImpl.java:155) ~[hibernate-core-6.2.2.Final.jar:6.2.2.Final]
    at org.hibernate.tool.schema.internal.SchemaDropperImpl.doDrop(SchemaDropperImpl.java:115) ~[hibernate-core-6.2.2.Final.jar:6.2.2.Final]
    at org.hibernate.tool.schema.spi.SchemaManagementToolCoordinator.performDatabaseAction(SchemaManagementToolCoordinator.java:242) ~[hibernate-core-6.2.2.Final.jar:6.2.2.Final]
    at org.hibernate.tool.schema.spi.SchemaManagementToolCoordinator.lambda$process$5(SchemaManagementToolCoordinator.java:143) ~[hibernate-core-6.2.2.Final.jar:6.2.2.Final]
    at java.base/java.util.HashMap.forEach(HashMap.java:1421) ~[na:na]
    at org.hibernate.tool.schema.spi.SchemaManagementToolCoordinator.process(SchemaManagementToolCoordinator.java:140) ~[hibernate-core-6.2.2.Final.jar:6.2.2.Final]
    at org.hibernate.boot.internal.SessionFactoryObserverForSchemaExport.sessionFactoryCreated(SessionFactoryObserverForSchemaExport.java:37) ~[hibernate-core-6.2.2.Final.jar:6.2.2.Final]
    at org.hibernate.internal.SessionFactoryObserverChain.sessionFactoryCreated(SessionFactoryObserverChain.java:35) ~[hibernate-core-6.2.2.Final.jar:6.2.2.Final]
    at org.hibernate.internal.SessionFactoryImpl.<init>(SessionFactoryImpl.java:291) ~[hibernate-core-6.2.2.Final.jar:6.2.2.Final]
    at org.hibernate.boot.internal.SessionFactoryBuilderImpl.build(SessionFactoryBuilderImpl.java:431) ~[hibernate-core-6.2.2.Final.jar:6.2.2.Final]
    at org.hibernate.jpa.boot.internal.EntityManagerFactoryBuilderImpl.build(EntityManagerFactoryBuilderImpl.java:1455) ~[hibernate-core-6.2.2.Final.jar:6.2.2.Final]
    at org.springframework.orm.jpa.vendor.SpringHibernateJpaPersistenceProvider.createContainerEntityManagerFactory(SpringHibernateJpaPersistenceProvider.java:66) ~[spring-orm-6.0.9.jar:6.0.9]
    at org.springframework.orm.jpa.LocalContainerEntityManagerFactoryBean.createNativeEntityManagerFactory(LocalContainerEntityManagerFactoryBean.java:376) ~[spring-orm-6.0.9.jar:6.0.9]
    at org.springframework.orm.jpa.AbstractEntityManagerFactoryBean.buildNativeEntityManagerFactory(AbstractEntityManagerFactoryBean.java:409) ~[spring-orm-6.0.9.jar:6.0.9]
    at org.springframework.orm.jpa.AbstractEntityManagerFactoryBean.afterPropertiesSet(AbstractEntityManagerFactoryBean.java:396) ~[spring-orm-6.0.9.jar:6.0.9]
    at org.springframework.orm.jpa.LocalContainerEntityManagerFactoryBean.afterPropertiesSet(LocalContainerEntityManagerFactoryBean.java:352) ~[spring-orm-6.0.9.jar:6.0.9]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.invokeInitMethods(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:1816) ~[spring-beans-6.0.9.jar:6.0.9]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.initializeBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:1766) ~[spring-beans-6.0.9.jar:6.0.9]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.doCreateBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:598) ~[spring-beans-6.0.9.jar:6.0.9]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.createBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:520) ~[spring-beans-6.0.9.jar:6.0.9]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.lambda$doGetBean$0(AbstractBeanFactory.java:326) ~[spring-beans-6.0.9.jar:6.0.9]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultSingletonBeanRegistry.getSingleton(DefaultSingletonBeanRegistry.java:234) ~[spring-beans-6.0.9.jar:6.0.9]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.doGetBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:324) ~[spring-beans-6.0.9.jar:6.0.9]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.getBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:200) ~[spring-beans-6.0.9.jar:6.0.9]
    at org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.getBean(AbstractApplicationContext.java:1156) ~[spring-context-6.0.9.jar:6.0.9]
    at org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.finishBeanFactoryInitialization(AbstractApplicationContext.java:931) ~[spring-context-6.0.9.jar:6.0.9]
    at org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.refresh(AbstractApplicationContext.java:608) ~[spring-context-6.0.9.jar:6.0.9]
    at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.refresh(SpringApplication.java:733) ~[spring-boot-3.1.0.jar:3.1.0]
    at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.refreshContext(SpringApplication.java:435) ~[spring-boot-3.1.0.jar:3.1.0]
    at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.run(SpringApplication.java:311) ~[spring-boot-3.1.0.jar:3.1.0]
    at org.springframework.boot.test.context.SpringBootContextLoader.lambda$loadContext$3(SpringBootContextLoader.java:137) ~[spring-boot-test-3.1.0.jar:3.1.0]
    at org.springframework.util.function.ThrowingSupplier.get(ThrowingSupplier.java:58) ~[spring-core-6.0.9.jar:6.0.9]
    at org.springframework.util.function.ThrowingSupplier.get(ThrowingSupplier.java:46) ~[spring-core-6.0.9.jar:6.0.9]
    at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.withHook(SpringApplication.java:1405) ~[spring-boot-3.1.0.jar:3.1.0]
    at org.springframework.boot.test.context.SpringBootContextLoader$ContextLoaderHook.run(SpringBootContextLoader.java:545) ~[spring-boot-test-3.1.0.jar:3.1.0]
    at org.springframework.boot.test.context.SpringBootContextLoader.loadContext(SpringBootContextLoader.java:137) ~[spring-boot-test-3.1.0.jar:3.1.0]
    at org.springframework.boot.test.context.SpringBootContextLoader.loadContext(SpringBootContextLoader.java:108) ~[spring-boot-test-3.1.0.jar:3.1.0]
    at org.springframework.test.context.cache.DefaultCacheAwareContextLoaderDelegate.loadContextInternal(DefaultCacheAwareContextLoaderDelegate.java:184) ~[spring-test-6.0.9.jar:6.0.9]
    at org.springframework.test.context.cache.DefaultCacheAwareContextLoaderDelegate.loadContext(DefaultCacheAwareContextLoaderDelegate.java:118) ~[spring-test-6.0.9.jar:6.0.9]
    at org.springframework.test.context.support.DefaultTestContext.getApplicationContext(DefaultTestContext.java:127) ~[spring-test-6.0.9.jar:6.0.9]
    at org.springframework.test.context.support.DependencyInjectionTestExecutionListener.injectDependencies(DependencyInjectionTestExecutionListener.java:141) ~[spring-test-6.0.9.jar:6.0.9]
    at org.springframework.test.context.support.DependencyInjectionTestExecutionListener.prepareTestInstance(DependencyInjectionTestExecutionListener.java:97) ~[spring-test-6.0.9.jar:6.0.9]
    at org.springframework.test.context.TestContextManager.prepareTestInstance(TestContextManager.java:241) ~[spring-test-6.0.9.jar:6.0.9]
    at org.springframework.test.context.junit.jupiter.SpringExtension.postProcessTestInstance(SpringExtension.java:138) ~[spring-test-6.0.9.jar:6.0.9]
    at org.junit.jupiter.engine.descriptor.ClassBasedTestDescriptor.lambda$invokeTestInstancePostProcessors$10(ClassBasedTestDescriptor.java:377) ~[junit-jupiter-engine-5.9.3.jar:5.9.3]
    at org.junit.jupiter.engine.descriptor.ClassBasedTestDescriptor.executeAndMaskThrowable(ClassBasedTestDescriptor.java:382) ~[junit-jupiter-engine-5.9.3.jar:5.9.3]
    at org.junit.jupiter.engine.descriptor.ClassBasedTestDescriptor.lambda$invokeTestInstancePostProcessors$11(ClassBasedTestDescriptor.java:377) ~[junit-jupiter-engine-5.9.3.jar:5.9.3]
    at java.base/java.util.stream.ReferencePipeline$3$1.accept(ReferencePipeline.java:197) ~[na:na]
    at java.base/java.util.stream.ReferencePipeline$2$1.accept(ReferencePipeline.java:179) ~[na:na]
    at java.base/java.util.ArrayList$ArrayListSpliterator.forEachRemaining(ArrayList.java:1625) ~[na:na]
    at java.base/java.util.stream.AbstractPipeline.copyInto(AbstractPipeline.java:509) ~[na:na]
    at java.base/java.util.stream.AbstractPipeline.wrapAndCopyInto(AbstractPipeline.java:499) ~[na:na]
    at java.base/java.util.stream.StreamSpliterators$WrappingSpliterator.forEachRemaining(StreamSpliterators.java:310) ~[na:na]
    at java.base/java.util.stream.Streams$ConcatSpliterator.forEachRemaining(Streams.java:735) ~[na:na]
    at java.base/java.util.stream.Streams$ConcatSpliterator.forEachRemaining(Streams.java:734) ~[na:na]
    at java.base/java.util.stream.ReferencePipeline$Head.forEach(ReferencePipeline.java:762) ~[na:na]
    at org.junit.jupiter.engine.descriptor.ClassBasedTestDescriptor.invokeTestInstancePostProcessors(ClassBasedTestDescriptor.java:376) ~[junit-jupiter-engine-5.9.3.jar:5.9.3]
    at org.junit.jupiter.engine.descriptor.ClassBasedTestDescriptor.lambda$instantiateAndPostProcessTestInstance$6(ClassBasedTestDescriptor.java:289) ~[junit-jupiter-engine-5.9.3.jar:5.9.3]
    at org.junit.platform.engine.support.hierarchical.ThrowableCollector.execute(ThrowableCollector.java:73) ~[junit-platform-engine-1.9.3.jar:1.9.3]
    at org.junit.jupiter.engine.descriptor.ClassBasedTestDescriptor.instantiateAndPostProcessTestInstance(ClassBasedTestDescriptor.java:288) ~[junit-jupiter-engine-5.9.3.jar:5.9.3]
    at org.junit.jupiter.engine.descriptor.ClassBasedTestDescriptor.lambda$testInstancesProvider$4(ClassBasedTestDescriptor.java:278) ~[junit-jupiter-engine-5.9.3.jar:5.9.3]
    at java.base/java.util.Optional.orElseGet(Optional.java:364) ~[na:na]
    at org.junit.jupiter.engine.descriptor.ClassBasedTestDescriptor.lambda$testInstancesProvider$5(ClassBasedTestDescriptor.java:277) ~[junit-jupiter-engine-5.9.3.jar:5.9.3]
    at org.junit.jupiter.engine.execution.TestInstancesProvider.getTestInstances(TestInstancesProvider.java:31) ~[junit-jupiter-engine-5.9.3.jar:5.9.3]
    at org.junit.jupiter.engine.descriptor.TestMethodTestDescriptor.lambda$prepare$0(TestMethodTestDescriptor.java:105) ~[junit-jupiter-engine-5.9.3.jar:5.9.3]
    at org.junit.platform.engine.support.hierarchical.ThrowableCollector.execute(ThrowableCollector.java:73) ~[junit-platform-engine-1.9.3.jar:1.9.3]
    at org.junit.jupiter.engine.descriptor.TestMethodTestDescriptor.prepare(TestMethodTestDescriptor.java:104) ~[junit-jupiter-engine-5.9.3.jar:5.9.3]
    at org.junit.jupiter.engine.descriptor.TestMethodTestDescriptor.prepare(TestMethodTestDescriptor.java:68) ~[junit-jupiter-engine-5.9.3.jar:5.9.3]
    at org.junit.platform.engine.support.hierarchical.NodeTestTask.lambda$prepare$2(NodeTestTask.java:123) ~[junit-platform-engine-1.9.3.jar:1.9.3]
    at org.junit.platform.engine.support.hierarchical.ThrowableCollector.execute(ThrowableCollector.java:73) ~[junit-platform-engine-1.9.3.jar:1.9.3]
    at org.junit.platform.engine.support.hierarchical.NodeTestTask.prepare(NodeTestTask.java:123) ~[junit-platform-engine-1.9.3.jar:1.9.3]
    at org.junit.platform.engine.support.hierarchical.NodeTestTask.execute(NodeTestTask.java:90) ~[junit-platform-engine-1.9.3.jar:1.9.3]
    at java.base/java.util.ArrayList.forEach(ArrayList.java:1511) ~[na:na]
    at org.junit.platform.engine.support.hierarchical.SameThreadHierarchicalTestExecutorService.invokeAll(SameThreadHierarchicalTestExecutorService.java:41) ~[junit-platform-engine-1.9.3.jar:1.9.3]
    at org.junit.platform.engine.support.hierarchical.NodeTestTask.lambda$executeRecursively$6(NodeTestTask.java:155) ~[junit-platform-engine-1.9.3.jar:1.9.3]
    at org.junit.platform.engine.support.hierarchical.ThrowableCollector.execute(ThrowableCollector.java:73) ~[junit-platform-engine-1.9.3.jar:1.9.3]
    at org.junit.platform.engine.support.hierarchical.NodeTestTask.lambda$executeRecursively$8(NodeTestTask.java:141) ~[junit-platform-engine-1.9.3.jar:1.9.3]
    at org.junit.platform.engine.support.hierarchical.Node.around(Node.java:137) ~[junit-platform-engine-1.9.3.jar:1.9.3]
    at org.junit.platform.engine.support.hierarchical.NodeTestTask.lambda$executeRecursively$9(NodeTestTask.java:139) ~[junit-platform-engine-1.9.3.jar:1.9.3]
    at org.junit.platform.engine.support.hierarchical.ThrowableCollector.execute(ThrowableCollector.java:73) ~[junit-platform-engine-1.9.3.jar:1.9.3]
    at org.junit.platform.engine.support.hierarchical.NodeTestTask.executeRecursively(NodeTestTask.java:138) ~[junit-platform-engine-1.9.3.jar:1.9.3]
    at org.junit.platform.engine.support.hierarchical.NodeTestTask.execute(NodeTestTask.java:95) ~[junit-platform-engine-1.9.3.jar:1.9.3]
    at java.base/java.util.ArrayList.forEach(ArrayList.java:1511) ~[na:na]
    at org.junit.platform.engine.support.hierarchical.SameThreadHierarchicalTestExecutorService.invokeAll(SameThreadHierarchicalTestExecutorService.java:41) ~[junit-platform-engine-1.9.3.jar:1.9.3]
    at org.junit.platform.engine.support.hierarchical.NodeTestTask.lambda$executeRecursively$6(NodeTestTask.java:155) ~[junit-platform-engine-1.9.3.jar:1.9.3]
    at org.junit.platform.engine.support.hierarchical.ThrowableCollector.execute(ThrowableCollector.java:73) ~[junit-platform-engine-1.9.3.jar:1.9.3]
    at org.junit.platform.engine.support.hierarchical.NodeTestTask.lambda$executeRecursively$8(NodeTestTask.java:141) ~[junit-platform-engine-1.9.3.jar:1.9.3]
    at org.junit.platform.engine.support.hierarchical.Node.around(Node.java:137) ~[junit-platform-engine-1.9.3.jar:1.9.3]
    at org.junit.platform.engine.support.hierarchical.NodeTestTask.lambda$executeRecursively$9(NodeTestTask.java:139) ~[junit-platform-engine-1.9.3.jar:1.9.3]
    at org.junit.platform.engine.support.hierarchical.ThrowableCollector.execute(ThrowableCollector.java:73) ~[junit-platform-engine-1.9.3.jar:1.9.3]
    at org.junit.platform.engine.support.hierarchical.NodeTestTask.executeRecursively(NodeTestTask.java:138) ~[junit-platform-engine-1.9.3.jar:1.9.3]
    at org.junit.platform.engine.support.hierarchical.NodeTestTask.execute(NodeTestTask.java:95) ~[junit-platform-engine-1.9.3.jar:1.9.3]
    at org.junit.platform.engine.support.hierarchical.SameThreadHierarchicalTestExecutorService.submit(SameThreadHierarchicalTestExecutorService.java:35) ~[junit-platform-engine-1.9.3.jar:1.9.3]
    at org.junit.platform.engine.support.hierarchical.HierarchicalTestExecutor.execute(HierarchicalTestExecutor.java:57) ~[junit-platform-engine-1.9.3.jar:1.9.3]
    at org.junit.platform.engine.support.hierarchical.HierarchicalTestEngine.execute(HierarchicalTestEngine.java:54) ~[junit-platform-engine-1.9.3.jar:1.9.3]
    at org.junit.platform.launcher.core.EngineExecutionOrchestrator.execute(EngineExecutionOrchestrator.java:147) ~[junit-platform-launcher-1.9.3.jar:1.9.3]
    at org.junit.platform.launcher.core.EngineExecutionOrchestrator.execute(EngineExecutionOrchestrator.java:127) ~[junit-platform-launcher-1.9.3.jar:1.9.3]
    at org.junit.platform.launcher.core.EngineExecutionOrchestrator.execute(EngineExecutionOrchestrator.java:90) ~[junit-platform-launcher-1.9.3.jar:1.9.3]
    at org.junit.platform.launcher.core.EngineExecutionOrchestrator.lambda$execute$0(EngineExecutionOrchestrator.java:55) ~[junit-platform-launcher-1.9.3.jar:1.9.3]
    at org.junit.platform.launcher.core.EngineExecutionOrchestrator.withInterceptedStreams(EngineExecutionOrchestrator.java:102) ~[junit-platform-launcher-1.9.3.jar:1.9.3]
    at org.junit.platform.launcher.core.EngineExecutionOrchestrator.execute(EngineExecutionOrchestrator.java:54) ~[junit-platform-launcher-1.9.3.jar:1.9.3]
    at org.junit.platform.launcher.core.DefaultLauncher.execute(DefaultLauncher.java:114) ~[junit-platform-launcher-1.9.3.jar:1.9.3]
    at org.junit.platform.launcher.core.DefaultLauncher.execute(DefaultLauncher.java:86) ~[junit-platform-launcher-1.9.3.jar:1.9.3]
    at org.junit.platform.launcher.core.DefaultLauncherSession$DelegatingLauncher.execute(DefaultLauncherSession.java:86) ~[junit-platform-launcher-1.9.3.jar:1.9.3]
    at org.junit.platform.launcher.core.SessionPerRequestLauncher.execute(SessionPerRequestLauncher.java:53) ~[junit-platform-launcher-1.9.3.jar:1.9.3]
    at com.intellij.junit5.JUnit5IdeaTestRunner.startRunnerWithArgs(JUnit5IdeaTestRunner.java:57) ~[junit5-rt.jar:na]
    at com.intellij.rt.junit.IdeaTestRunner$Repeater$1.execute(IdeaTestRunner.java:38) ~[junit-rt.jar:na]
    at com.intellij.rt.execution.junit.TestsRepeater.repeat(TestsRepeater.java:11) ~[idea_rt.jar:na]
    at com.intellij.rt.junit.IdeaTestRunner$Repeater.startRunnerWithArgs(IdeaTestRunner.java:35) ~[junit-rt.jar:na]
    at com.intellij.rt.junit.JUnitStarter.prepareStreamsAndStart(JUnitStarter.java:232) ~[junit-rt.jar:na]
    at com.intellij.rt.junit.JUnitStarter.main(JUnitStarter.java:55) ~[junit-rt.jar:na]
Caused by: java.sql.SQLSyntaxErrorException: Table 'test.tab_house' doesn't exist
    at com.mysql.cj.jdbc.exceptions.SQLError.createSQLException(SQLError.java:121) ~[mysql-connector-j-8.0.33.jar:8.0.33]
    at com.mysql.cj.jdbc.exceptions.SQLExceptionsMapping.translateException(SQLExceptionsMapping.java:122) ~[mysql-connector-j-8.0.33.jar:8.0.33]
    at com.mysql.cj.jdbc.StatementImpl.executeInternal(StatementImpl.java:763) ~[mysql-connector-j-8.0.33.jar:8.0.33]
    at com.mysql.cj.jdbc.StatementImpl.execute(StatementImpl.java:648) ~[mysql-connector-j-8.0.33.jar:8.0.33]
    at com.zaxxer.hikari.pool.ProxyStatement.execute(ProxyStatement.java:94) ~[HikariCP-5.0.1.jar:na]
    at com.zaxxer.hikari.pool.HikariProxyStatement.execute(HikariProxyStatement.java) ~[HikariCP-5.0.1.jar:na]
    at org.hibernate.tool.schema.internal.exec.GenerationTargetToDatabase.accept(GenerationTargetToDatabase.java:78) ~[hibernate-core-6.2.2.Final.jar:6.2.2.Final]
    ... 117 common frames omitted





Hibernate: drop table if exists tab_house
Hibernate: create table tab_house (pro_house bigint not null,...) engine=InnoDB
Hibernate: alter table tab_house add constraint FK_HOUSE_PRO foreign key (pro_house) references tab_profile (id)
2023-05-26T13:28:58.727+02:00  WARN 250759 --- [           main] o.h.t.s.i.ExceptionHandlerLoggedImpl     : GenerationTarget encountered exception accepting command : Error executing DDL "alter table tab_house add constraint FK_HOUSE_PRO foreign key (pro_house) references tab_profile (id)" via JDBC [Duplicate foreign key constraint name 'FK_HOUSE_PRO']

org.hibernate.tool.schema.spi.CommandAcceptanceException: Error executing DDL "alter table tab_house add constraint FK_HOUSE_PRO foreign key (pro_house) references tab_profile (id)" via JDBC [Duplicate foreign key constraint name 'FK_HOUSE_PRO']
...
...
...
Caused by: java.sql.SQLException: Duplicate foreign key constraint name 'FK_HOUSE_PRO'
    at com.mysql.cj.jdbc.exceptions.SQLError.createSQLException(SQLError.java:130) ~[mysql-connector-j-8.0.33.jar:8.0.33]
...
...
...
```

I had to crop the exception.
Despite these errors, the test still runs successfully. But it doesn't feel right when these exceptions are thrown.

My minimal test class setup look like follows:

```
spring:
  profiles:
    active: test
  jpa:
    hibernate:
      ddl-auto: create-drop
```

```
@DataJpaTest
public class HouseRepositoryTest implements TestDbContainerInitializer {
    @Autowired
    private HouseRepository houseRepository;

    @Test
    public void tester() {
        assert 0 == projectRepository.findAll().size();
    }

}
```

```
@Testcontainers(disabledWithoutDocker = true)
public interface TestDbContainerInitializer {

    @Container
    public static MySQLContainer<TestDbContainer> mySQLContainer = TestDbContainer.getInstance();

    @DynamicPropertySource
    static void registerMySqlProperties(DynamicPropertyRegistry registry) {
        registry.add("spring.datasource.url", mySQLContainer::getJdbcUrl);
        registry.add("spring.datasource.username", mySQLContainer::getUsername);
        registry.add("spring.datasource.password", mySQLContainer::getPassword);
        registry.add("spring.datasource.driver-class-name",()->"com.mysql.cj.jdbc.Driver");
        registry.add("spring.test.database.replace",()->"none");
    }
}
```

```
public class TestDbContainer extends MySQLContainer<TestDbContainer> {
    public static final String IMAGE_VERSION = "mysql:8.0.33";
    public static TestDbContainer container;

    private TestDbContainer() {
        super(IMAGE_VERSION);
    }

    public static TestDbContainer getInstance() {
        if (container == null) {
            container = new TestDbContainer();
        }
        return container;
    }

    @Override
    public void stop() {
        // Don't stop between Tests. Keep Container running. Let JVM handle shut down after all Tests has been run
    }
```

Comment: I'm now able to reproduce it. Can you share a repository to reproduce the problem, please?

Comment: Here is a minimal Repository which triggers said exceptions when running ProjectRepositoryTest: https://github.com/jbcbezerra/springboot-tc

Comment: I had the most problems with this (latest) image version and a huge "warm up time"... PR is coming ;)

Comment: Works great. I left some suggestions in your PR. The most of it came down to the use of springboots testcontainer dependency and changes in the application.yml.
Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Few things to consider, you are using flyway for database change management but also using `spring.jpa.hibernate.ddl-auto: create-drop`. Choose one. Close to prod, I would choose flyway. The main problem is there indeed because once flyway scripts are executed then hibernate will drop the schema and create a new one, when dropping the existing one (created by flyway), the table is not found because `TABLE_A` is different than `table_a`, uppercase vs lowercase. You can check your mysql configuration. In order to fix the example provided just update the flyway script with lowercase and no error will be displayed when running the tests.